# How to set cc_number_enc on order saving?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment

I need to save credit card number with encryption. Where i need to add something to encrypt it from cc_number?
Maybe write plugin or observer for some method?

Answer (score 0):

Same as Magento 1, You need to add following code into your payment model class.

```
/**
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_canSaveCc = true;
```